# logging into google using selenuim automaticlly

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

so the code below is supposed to open google chrome loged into my google account but it gives an on screen error but after clicking the ok button or exit works perfectly is there a way to make the error either not happen or just automaticlly click ok or the exit button in the error popup

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# Set path to chromedriver
chrome_driver = "/path/to/chromedriver"

# Add desired arguments to ChromeOptions object
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized") # Opens Chrome maximized
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars") # Disables infobar messages

options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir=profile_Profile 1') # Path to your Google account profile # Path to your Google account profile # Path to your Google account profile

# Initialize Chrome driver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Would you be able to give some details of exactly what error you're getting? Including the stack trace would also be helpful

Comment: @B.Griffin thanks for your message i already fixed the issue sorry for being late to respond